# SQL query in Access with out using the criteria field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out a SQL query that will allow me to select from an InputBox a single Damage# to the exclusion of the others. If I use a something like [Enter a Damage Number], I get an error message of Runtime error '2482: Microsoft Access can't find the name 'Enter a Damage Number' you entered in the expression. By selecting the damage #, the other fields will export to an Excel spreadsheet for all the records with that one damage number rather than all the records in the table.

```sql
SELECT CompsT.Damages, CompsT.Component, CompsT.[Location Grouping], CompsT.[Component Description], CompsT.[Make/Model/Type], CompsT.COD, CompsT.[Dimension Type], CompsT.Length, CompsT.LUnit, CompsT.Wide, CompsT.WUnit, CompsT.High, CompsT.HUnit, CompsT.Depth, CompsT.DUnit, CompsT.[Quantity Type], CompsT.[Quantity Unit], CompsT.Quantity, CompsT.[Work Complete]
FROM CompsT
WHERE (((CompsT.Damages)=[Enter a Damage #]));
```

If I leave off the WHERE statement, it returns all the records from the table.

Comment: I have tested it w/o any issue on Microsoft 365. Please try `WHERE CompsT.Damages=[Enter a Damage #]` although extra bracket isn't a problem in general.

Comment: I never use popup input prompts in query. I do not use dynamic criteria in query. I apply filter criteria to form or report. I would export a simple report or use VBA QueryDefs to modify query object. The parentheses are not issue. Is Damages a text field? If so, need apostrophe delimiters.